# Overload resolution finds functions after template instantiation point

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, overload-resolution

In the following code `main` returns `2` while I expect it to return `0` (or at least `7`)

```cpp
extern struct S s;
template<typename T>
constexpr int global(T&) { return 0; }

template<typename T>
//constexpr
int func(T& t) { return global(t); }

int main()
{
    return global(s) + 2*func(s) + 4*([](auto &a){return global(a);})(s);
}

static constexpr int global(S&) { return 1; }
```

This code is also on https://godbolt.org/z/RkkXwf

If I uncomment `constexpr` on `func` the result changes to the expected `0`.

From what I understand the overload resolution should only consider functions before template instantiation point. But somehow it finds the one declared after this point for context that is neither `constexpr` nor generic lambda.

Why do these three lookups find different functions?

Comment: A guess as to why: When the compiler does the second-phase lookup when instantiating `func`, it's already first-phase compiled the non-template global and can use it in the set of overload candidates. If I have a little time later I'll try to see if I can find anything in the standard.

Comment: There is a point of instantiation for function templates at the end of the translation unit.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I didn't know about it. That proves that the program is ill-formed which answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by n.m. in a comment, function templates may be instantiated at the end of the translation unit, see [#993](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#993) and [temp.point](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#7.2). The same paragraph says "If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."

Comment: To add to this, I'd imagine that marking the function `constexpr` encourages the compiler to instantiate it right away in case it is needed to evaluate a constant expression (though the program remains ill-formed NDR). I'm not sure about why the lambda is treated differently though.

Comment: A colleague of mine, Sam Conrad, found the relevant locations in clang...

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/Sema/Sema.cpp#L886 - the comment shows that it is unable to give a diagnostic
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/lib/Sema/SemaDecl.cpp#L13160 - gives the conditions under which clang can delay the instantiation

Comment: The second location explicitly calls out constexpr function templates, probably for exactly the reason you said, that it may otherwise be needed. It also explicitly calls out deduced return types, presumably because the return type may be needed. The lambda has a deduced return type, and in C++17 and above it is constexpr, but not in C++14.

Comment: Good catch! I forgot that lambdas have deduced return types.